# How to add loading effect in website?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website but i have no idea about page loading effect.
I have tried using effect shown in website [http://www.realcombiz.com/2013/12/35-amazing-loading-animation-effects.html] but it is just showing animation on the website, rather than showing at the time of page loading.

Comment: create a div and make it abosute to center and set some loading image init. Now you your service is called make it visible other vise hide it. using script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this out ,it shows the first loading effect in your link given](http://jsfiddle.net/3KAnM/11/)

### HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
    <!--  <img src="http://cdn.nirmaltv.com/images/generatorphp-thumb.gif" alt="Wait" alt="Loading" />-->
    <div class="circ">
  <div class="load">Loading...</div>
  <div class="hands"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="eye"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlayText">


        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"  >

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
```

### Jquery

```
    //  1.0);This sets the opacity to 100% on hover },function(){ 


var delay = 3000;
setTimeout(function() 

    {  

        $( "#overlay" ).fadeOut( "slow" );

         $('#container').fadeIn();

    },
    delay
) ;
```

### CSS

```
#overlayText{
     position:absolute;
    top:365px;
    left: 330px;

   z-index:11;

}

#container{
    position:relative;
       display:none;
}
#overlay{

  width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:#222;
    opacity:0.7;



}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One);
html{width: 100%;height: 100%;}


.eye{
  width: 20px; height: 8px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  box-shadow:  40px 0px 0px 0px #eee;              
}

.head{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: -250px auto;
  width: 80px; height: 80px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius:50px;
  box-shadow: inset -4px 2px 0px 0px #eee;
    -webkit-animation:node 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
}
.body{ 
  position: relative;
  margin: 90px auto;
  width: 140px; height: 120px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50px/25px ;
  box-shadow: inset -5px 2px 0px 0px #eee;
  -webkit-animation:node2 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;  
}

  @-webkit-keyframes node 
      {
         0%{ top:0px; }
         50%{ top:10px; }
         100% { top:0px;} 
       }

  @-webkit-keyframes node2
      {
         0%{ top:-5px; }
         50%{ top:10px; }
         100% { top:-5px;} 
       }

.circ{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   margin: 60px auto;
  width: 180px; height: 180px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;  
  left: 0%;
  top: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hands{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 140px;
  width: 120px;height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius:20px;
  box-shadow:-1px -4px 0px 0px #eee;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  top:75%;left: 16%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation:node2 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
}

.load{  position: absolute;
  width: 100px; height: 20px;
   margin: -10px auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:400;
  color:#eee;
  left: 10%;
  top: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add loading image or style on load function -

```
$(window).load(function() {      

});
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {      
   $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```css
body{
 background:url('http://www.artswallpapers.net/minimalist-abstract-wallpapers/images/104.jpg');
}
#loader{
 background: url('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/34535/screenshots/631316/loader_gif.gif');
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">
  
 </div>
 <div class="wrap">

 </div>
```